# How did Pareto derive this equation to represent income distribution and why is the use of logarithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, systems-of-equations, normal-distribution

Vilfredo Pareto argued that in all countries and times, the distribution of income and wealth is highly skewed, with a few holding most of the wealth. He argued that all observed societies follow a regular logarithmic pattern (as given in *The Story of Econophysics* by K. C. Dash, p.26):
**log N = log A + m log x**,

where N is the number of people with wealth higher than x, and A and m are constants.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you're asking for economic and not mathematical intuitions, so this probably isn't the most appropriate forum.